# Parallel and sequential runs give different results in FiPy when using periodic mesh

Tags: python, fipy

I have run the following code to simulate a flow around a cylinder in a 2D mesh:

```py
from fipy import CellVariable, FaceVariable, Grid2D, DiffusionTerm, ImplicitSourceTerm, PeriodicGrid2DTopBottom, DistanceVariable, Viewer
from fipy.tools import numerix

L = 1.0
N = 50
dL = L / N
viscosity = 1
U = 1.
#0.8 for pressure and 0.5 for velocity are typical relaxation values for SIMPLE
pressureRelaxation = 0.8
velocityRelaxation = 0.5
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sweeps = 500
else:
    sweeps = 5


mesh = PeriodicGrid2DTopBottom(nx=N, ny=N, dx=dL, dy=dL)

pressure = CellVariable(mesh=mesh, name='pressure')
pressureCorrection = CellVariable(mesh=mesh)
xVelocity = CellVariable(mesh=mesh, name='X velocity')
yVelocity = CellVariable(mesh=mesh, name='Y velocity')

velocity = FaceVariable(mesh=mesh, rank=1)

pfi=3000.
lfi=0.01
x, y = mesh.cellCenters
var1 = DistanceVariable(name='distance to center', mesh=mesh, value=numerix.sqrt((x-N*dL/2.)**2+(y-N*dL/2.)**2))
rad=0.1
pi_fi= CellVariable(mesh=mesh, value=0.,name='Fluid-interface energy map')
pi_fi.setValue(pfi*numerix.exp(-1.*(var1-rad)/lfi), where=(var1 > rad) )
pi_fi.setValue(pfi, where=(var1 <= rad))
xVelocityEq = DiffusionTerm(coeff=viscosity) - pressure.grad.dot([1., 0.]) - ImplicitSourceTerm(pi_fi)
yVelocityEq = DiffusionTerm(coeff=viscosity) - pressure.grad.dot([0., 1.]) - ImplicitSourceTerm(pi_fi)

ap = CellVariable(mesh=mesh, value=1.)
coeff = 1./ ap.arithmeticFaceValue*mesh._faceAreas * mesh._cellDistances
pressureCorrectionEq = DiffusionTerm(coeff=coeff) - velocity.divergence

from fipy.variables.faceGradVariable import _FaceGradVariable
volume = CellVariable(mesh=mesh, value=mesh.cellVolumes, name='Volume')
contrvolume=volume.arithmeticFaceValue

xVelocity.constrain(U, mesh.facesLeft | mesh.facesRight)
yVelocity.constrain(0., mesh.facesLeft | mesh.facesRight)

X, Y = mesh.faceCenters
pressureCorrection.constrain(0., mesh.facesLeft & (Y < dL))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    viewer = Viewer(vars=(pressure, xVelocity, yVelocity, velocity),
               xmin=0., xmax=1., ymin=0., ymax=1., colorbar=True)

from builtins import range
for sweep in range(sweeps):

    ## solve the Stokes equations to get starred values
    xVelocityEq.cacheMatrix()
    xres = xVelocityEq.sweep(var=xVelocity,
                             underRelaxation=velocityRelaxation)
    xmat = xVelocityEq.matrix

    yres = yVelocityEq.sweep(var=yVelocity,
                             underRelaxation=velocityRelaxation)

    ## update the ap coefficient from the matrix diagonal
    ap[:] = -numerix.asarray(xmat.takeDiagonal())

    ## update the face velocities based on starred values with the
    ## Rhie-Chow correction.
    ## cell pressure gradient
    presgrad = pressure.grad
    ## face pressure gradient
    facepresgrad = _FaceGradVariable(pressure)

    velocity[0] = xVelocity.arithmeticFaceValue \
         + contrvolume / ap.arithmeticFaceValue * \
           (presgrad[0].arithmeticFaceValue-facepresgrad[0])
    velocity[1] = yVelocity.arithmeticFaceValue \
         + contrvolume / ap.arithmeticFaceValue * \
           (presgrad[1].arithmeticFaceValue-facepresgrad[1])
    velocity[..., mesh.exteriorFaces.value] = 0.
    velocity[0, mesh.facesLeft.value] = U
    velocity[0, mesh.facesRight.value] = U

    ## solve the pressure correction equation
    pressureCorrectionEq.cacheRHSvector()
    ## left bottom point must remain at pressure 0, so no correction
    pres = pressureCorrectionEq.sweep(var=pressureCorrection)
    rhs = pressureCorrectionEq.RHSvector

    ## update the pressure using the corrected value
    pressure.setValue(pressure + pressureRelaxation * pressureCorrection )
    ## update the velocity using the corrected pressure
    xVelocity.setValue(xVelocity - pressureCorrection.grad[0] / \
                                               ap * mesh.cellVolumes)
    yVelocity.setValue(yVelocity - pressureCorrection.grad[1] / \
                                               ap * mesh.cellVolumes)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        if sweep%10 == 0:
            print('sweep:', sweep, ', x residual:', xres, \
                                 ', y residual', yres, \
                                 ', p residual:', pres, \
                                 ', continuity:', max(abs(rhs)))

            viewer.plot()

print(pressure.globalValue[..., 510])
print(xVelocity.globalValue[..., 510])
print(yVelocity.globalValue[..., 510])
```

This should solve the Navier-stokes equations with top/bottom periodic conditions and a cylinder in the center of the mesh (that's why there's an implicit source term in my equations). Velocity is equal to one at the left and at the right boundaries, and it is parallel to the x-axis. This example corresponds roughly to a flow through many cylindrical obstacles equally spaced. When I run it **without parallel computing**, pressure and velocity profiles look ok. The values printed for cell 510 are **2.788 (pressure), 1.104 (xvelocity) and -0.289 (yvelocity)**.
However, **when I run it in parallel mode (say using 2 processors)**, the profiles look weird. For the velocity profile, the plot between y= 0.2 and y= 0.8 is more or less similar to the plot from the sequential computing between y=0 and y=1. The pressure profile is quite different though. The values that are printed for cell 510 are **-3.163 (pressure), 1.209 (xvelocity) and -0.044 (yvelocity)**.
To use *Grid2D* instead of *PeriodicGrid2DTopBottom*, I included extra boundary conditions which I believe will be equivalent to using a periodic grid in this example. The new BCs are then:

```py
xVelocity.constrain(U, mesh.facesLeft | mesh.facesRight)
xVelocity.faceGrad.constrain(mesh.faceNormals * 0., where=mesh.facesBottom | mesh.facesTop)
yVelocity.constrain(0., mesh.exteriorFaces)
```

By doing so, I get the same output by running in sequential or in parallel with two processors: **2.784 (pressure), 1.104 (xvelocity) and -0.290 (yvelocity)**.
Were my boundary conditions underspecified when I used the periodic grid? (I guess that would explain two different solutions for the same problem) Or parallel computing and periodic meshes are not getting along for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, periodic meshes are currently [broken for parallel runs](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/issues/518).